# are IMP and @selector related?

Tags: objective-c, selector, imp

I've looking information related with IMP, but everything I find looks like an old practice.

I may be wrong but IMP represents the address of a method so you can pass it as an argument if you need to, right?
If this is true, doesn't @selector allow this?

I would appreciate if somebody can explain this to me because I'm really lost. It would be nice I can be provided with some information about using IMP and @selector.

Answer (score 1):

`@selector` resolves to a `SEL` which can be used to look up an `IMP`.  As you surmised, an `IMP` points to the implementation of a function, otherwise known as a function pointer.

What looks like this `[NSObject alloc]` in objective C looks like this in C:

```
objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("NSObject"),sel_getUid("alloc"))
```

Internally, `objc_msgSend` will take the provided `Class` and `SEL` and use something like `class_getMethodImplementation` to get the `IMP` to invoke.

It is generally better to use higher level interfaces like `Method` and functions like `NSSelectorFromString` and `NSClassFromString` to deal with the runtime.